# Reading characters off the screen

Tags: c#, vb.net, image, ocr

I've been trying to find a solution to my problem for quite a while. I need to build a program that reads data off the screen, recognizes characters and images and then acts based on what characters and images are. For example, I provide it with a picture of a dog, a picture of each possible character, and it would be able to read the screen and tell me where the dog was, where the characters were and in what order, etc. Is there a free library for this out somewhere? I prefer something that can be used in C# or Vb.net

Answer (score 0):

The general practice of recognizing characters and marks is called "optical character recognition" (OCR) and "optical mark recognition" (OMR).There are loads of options available, this is the top result in google:

http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v16/dh/to/leadtools.topics~leadtools.topics.usingomrinleadtoolsdotnetocr.html

However, if the ultimate goal is to solve ReCaptchas then you've got no chance.